# Passing PayPal Buttons items object

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have a bit of a head scratcher, I'm trying to make a store that sells one thing in three sizes and pass the items to paypal for payment:

```
            let itemsArray = [];
            let pplrg = parseInt(document.getElementById('lrg').value);
            let ppsml = parseInt(document.getElementById('sml').value);
            let ppcld = parseInt(document.getElementById('cld').value);
            let ppvalue = 0;
            if(pplrg > 0) {
                itemsArray.push({"name": "Adult Large", "description": "Adult Large size", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "AUD", "value": "25.95"}, "quantity": pplrg.toString()});
                ppvalue+= pplrg * 25.95
            }
            if(ppsml > 0) {
                itemsArray.push({"name": "Adult Small", "description": "Adult Small size", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "AUD", "value": "25.95"}, "quantity": ppsml.toString()});
                ppvalue+= ppsml * 25.95
            }
            if(ppcld > 0) {
                itemsArray.push({"name": "Child", "description": "Child size", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "AUD", "value": "24.95"}, "quantity": ppcld.toString()});
                ppvalue+= ppsml * 24.95
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
            
            paypal.Buttons({
                createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.order.create({
                     "purchase_units": [{
                        "amount": {
                          "currency_code": "AUD",
                          "value": ppvalue.toFixed(2),
                          "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                              "currency_code": "AUD",
                              "value": ppvalue.toFixed(2)
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "items": JSON.stringify(itemsArray)
                      }]
                  });
                },
                
                onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                    // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                        console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                        let transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                        let email = transaction.payer[0].email_address;
                        console.log(email);
                        alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');
                        
                    // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                    var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                    element.innerHTML = '';
                    element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                    element.innerHTML+= '<p>Paypal should be sending you an receipt with details of your order to '+email+'.</p>';
                  });
                }
            }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

This does not work, however, as you can see I `console.log` the contents of `JSON.stringify(itemsArray)` and if I replace `JSON.stringify(itemsArray)` in the paypal.Buttons with the contents of the console, it works fine. ie:

```
            let itemsArray = [];
            let pplrg = parseInt(document.getElementById('lrg').value);
            let ppsml = parseInt(document.getElementById('sml').value);
            let ppcld = parseInt(document.getElementById('cld').value);
            let ppvalue = 0;
            if(pplrg > 0) {
                itemsArray.push({"name": "Adult Large", "description": "Adult Large size", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "AUD", "value": "25.95"}, "quantity": pplrg.toString()});
                ppvalue+= pplrg * 25.95
            }
            if(ppsml > 0) {
                itemsArray.push({"name": "Adult Small", "description": "Adult Small size", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "AUD", "value": "25.95"}, "quantity": ppsml.toString()});
                ppvalue+= ppsml * 25.95
            }
            if(ppcld > 0) {
                itemsArray.push({"name": "Child", "description": "Child size", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "AUD", "value": "24.95"}, "quantity": ppcld.toString()});
                ppvalue+= ppsml * 24.95
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
            
            paypal.Buttons({
                createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.order.create({
                     "purchase_units": [{
                        "amount": {
                          "currency_code": "AUD",
                          "value": ppvalue.toFixed(2),
                          "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                              "currency_code": "AUD",
                              "value": ppvalue.toFixed(2)
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "items": [{"name":"'Adult Large","description":"Adult Large size","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"AUD","value":"25.95"},"quantity":"1"},{"name":"Adult Small","description":"Adult Small size","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"AUD","value":"25.95"},"quantity":"1"}]
                      }]
                  });
                },
                
                onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                    // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                        console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                        let transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                        let email = transaction.payer[0].email_address;
                        console.log(email);
                        alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');
                        
                    // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                    var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                    element.innerHTML = '';
                    element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                    element.innerHTML+= '<p>Paypal should be sending you an receipt with details of your order to '+email+'.</p>';
                  });
                }
            }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Which is what's really confusing me, obviously I've constructed my `itemsArray` correctly and `JSON.stringify(itemsArray)` renders the text in the format PayPal is expecting, but, it doesn't work, does anyone with a bit more experience be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've done a fair bit of searching on the issue and I know questions about this come up a bit but they all seem to be a fair bit different from the issue I'm having.

Comment: There's a rule of thumb: do not use stringify (or parse) unless you know exactly what you're doing. w3schools broke thousands of brains with their JSON object nonsense and we're all still suffering from this. You do not need to stringify anything here; just do `"items": itemsArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```js
"items": itemsArray
```

There is no cause to stringify something that's going to be assigned to a string value in an object that's later going to be stringified again for transmission.

Comment: A thousand thank you's! You kind, intelligent and beautiful person!